# Calculus formula with differentiation under integral

Tags: calculus

Is there a formula in calculus that says something like: Let $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Then,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon'}\left(g(\epsilon')\right) \bigg|_{\epsilon' = \epsilon\tau} ~\mathrm{d}\tau = \frac{g(\epsilon) - g(0)}{\epsilon}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of analysis combined with a simple substitution gives:
$$
\int_0^1 g'(\epsilon \tau) \, d\tau
= \{ \sigma=\epsilon \tau \}
= \int_0^{\epsilon} g'(\sigma) \, \epsilon^{-1} \, d\sigma
= \epsilon^{-1} \int_0^{\epsilon} g'(\sigma) \, d\sigma
= \epsilon^{-1} (g(\epsilon)-g(0))
= \frac{g(\epsilon)-g(0)}{\epsilon}.
$$